# "How to predict new data after dimensionality reduction with Isomap and LLE?" i m using RDRToolbox

Tags: predict, dimensionality-reduction

I have a data frame with 12 features and 39 individuals. I applied LLE, PCA and Isomap for feature reduction. I know how to get the loading matrix from PCA to predict a new data but i can t find a way to do the same thing with the other two approaches (LLE/Isomap)